# How can I create a custom function in AMPL?

Tags: function, ampl

In python, I would be able to define a function to, say, add one to x as follows:

```
def add_one(x):
    return x + 1
```

How can I define arbitrary functions in the AMPL language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has been already answered in [this AMPL Google Group post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/ampl/3wOsfI0z-iM/KkaNjvjlm60J):

> The AMPL language does not have a feature comparable to a Fortran subroutine or
>   C function.  At most, you can use "commands" to specify the execution of one
>   AMPL script within a loop in another AMPL script.
>
> You can also use AMPL's "shell" command within a loop, to call the executable
>   binary of a function that has been written and compiled in another language.
>   Communication between AMPL and the external function has to be via files,
>   though.
>
> A third possibility is to write a C program
>   that can be compiled into an executable binary -- a Windows dll or Unix shared
>   library -- that is accessible as a "user-defined function" within AMPL.  The
>   most detailed description of user-defined functions can be found in "Hooking
>   Your Solver to AMPL", www.ampl.com/REFS/abstracts.html#hooking2, pages 18-19.
>   There are also some further comments on this facility in later pages, with
>   references to example files available at www.netlib.org/ampl/solvers/examples.
>   Another example of implementing user-defined functions is given by Bob
>   Vanderbei at www.sor.princeton.edu/~rvdb/ampl/nlmodels.